# .py file converted to .exe. But unable to get the expected result

Tags: python, module, executable

I tried below code:

```
import os

def test1():

    os.system('cmd.exe /k ipconfig')

def main():

    task = raw_input('Enter your choice [1] :')
    if task=="1":
        test1()
        select=raw_input("Select y if you want to run the test again (y/n)")    
        if select=="y":
            main()
        else:
            print('No need to run the test again')

    else:
        print('Enter valid input')

main()
```

If I execute this in Python Idle I got the result as expected(Got command window pop up also after closing the command window, it is asking for 'Select y if you want to run the test again (y/n)') But After making this script as .exe(Executable) file, I am unable to get the command window pop up(Not getting the expected output from .exe as I am getting from Python Idle). How to solve this issue....?

Comment: How are you converting py to exe?

Comment: @DineshPundkar he is using pyinstaller.exe

Comment: @DineshPundkar Yes as Davit said, used pyinstaller.exe to convert .py to .exe

Comment: @DineshPundkar Plz change these lines to 'input' instead of 'raw_input' in above code and execute from cmd prompt... task = input('Enter your choice [1] :')  and select=input("Select y if you want to run the test again (y/n)") .Hope you will get the result, But not as you are getting the result from python editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from your code, looks like you want to open a new cmd displaying the ipconfig by running `os.system('cmd.exe /k ipconfig')`

but running `cmd.exe /k ipconfig` will not open a new window.

Instead try using `start cmd /k ipconfig` but this will not wait for the cmd to be closed. If you want to wait for it to be closed then ask if you want to test again, try `start /wait cmd /k ipconfig`

NOTE: make sure to run the .exe in the `dist` folder

Comment: Thanks for the response. Will try this and come back with the result.

Comment: Getting the expected result..Thanks again :)

Comment: Using this "os.system('ping 127.0.0.1 -t >> new.txt')".I am able to get the ping result in new.txt document. How to get the ping result in command window and text file at the same time in case of stream output like this...?

Comment: you can always save it in your new.txt file, and then output it in the console by saying `os.system('type new.txt')`